# Do I need gradle wrapper for each sub project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio automatically generates and creates gradle wrappers for each module/sub-project that is added.

Is this really necessary? Or can I just keep the one in the root project?

Also, when I run `gradle wrapper` to regenerate (e.g. to go to a newer version of gradle), it regenerates all the subproject ones as well. So, this also seems like overkill.

Any clarification & help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one located in the root project is enough. What may be useful for you is [this](https://github.com/cbeams/dotfiles/blob/home/bin/gradle) script. It enables running gradle wrapper from subprojects.

Comment: Do you have another link for this? The one referenced is broken.

Comment: I've gone through this repo history and it indeed disappeared. It seems that you can find similar script on the web. Just a shell function is needed.